# How to find all file owned by one user and copy them to another directory in RHEL 8?

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel8

Like I want to find all file owned by "user1" and copy those file to another folder "/root/found". Is this possible in redhat 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) like so:

```
find /path/to/source/dir -user 'user1' -exec cp {} /root/found/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Timur.